# Extract quotations and attribution from text

Tags: python, function, nlp, text-extraction, textacy

I am attempting to extract quotations and quotation attributions (i.e., the speaker) from text, but I am not obtaining the desired output. I am using textacy. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
import textacy
from textacy import extract
from textacy.representations import Vectorizer

data = [
        ("\"Hello, nice to meet you,\" said world 1", {"url": "example1.com", "date": "Jan 1"}),
        ("\"Hello, nice to meet you,\" said world 2", {"url": "example2.com", "date": "Jan 2"}),
        ]

corpus = textacy.Corpus("en_core_web_sm", data=data)

vectorizer = Vectorizer(tf_type="linear", idf_type="smooth")
doc = vectorizer.fit_transform(
    ((term.lemma_ for term in extract.terms(doc, ngs=1, ents=True)) for doc in corpus)
    ) 
         
quotes = (textacy.extract.triples.direct_quotations(doc) for records in doc)

print(list(quotes))
```

And here is the output:

> [<generator object direct_quotations at 0x7fdc0faaf6d0>, <generator object direct_quotations at 0x7fdc0faaf5f0>]

The desired output is something like this:

> [DQTriple(speaker=[world 1], cue=[said], content="Hello, nice to meet you,")]
> [DQTriple(speaker=[world 2], cue=[said], content="Hello, nice to meet you,")]

### EDIT

Here is some improved code, with the doc now created using the corpus, not data:

```
import textacy
from textacy import extract
from textacy.representations import Vectorizer

data = [
        ("\"Hello, nice to meet you,\" said world 1", {"url": "example1.com", "date": "Jan 1"}),
        ("\"Hello, nice to meet you,\" said world 2", {"url": "example2.com", "date": "Jan 2"}),
        ]

corpus = textacy.Corpus("en_core_web_sm", data=data)

vectorizer = Vectorizer(tf_type="linear", idf_type="smooth")
doc = vectorizer.fit_transform(
    ((term.lemma_ for term in extract.terms(corpus, ngs=1, ents=True)) for record in corpus)
    ) 
         
print(list((textacy.extract.triples.direct_quotations(doc))))
```

But now I have a new error:

> AttributeError: 'spacy.tokens.doc.Doc' object has no attribute 'is_space'

Comment: Did you try to turn the generators into a list (`list(textacy.extract.triples.direct_quotations(doc))`)?

Comment: Just tried, and that might be the right approach, but then I get the error `raise AttributeError(attr + " not found")
AttributeError: lang_ not found` which is what I have gotten with other approaches as well. So I think there are additional issues.

Comment: Look [here](https://textacy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#downloading-data) and [here](https://spacy.io/usage/models). You have to install the spaCy language-specific model data to fix that: `python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm`

Comment: I actually had that installed already, and just re-installed to be sure. Also installed `python -m textacy download lang_identifier --version 2.0`. Still got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```py
data = [
        ("\"Hello, nice to meet you,\" said world 1"),
        ("\"Hello, nice to meet you,\" said world 2"),
        ]
for record in data:
    doc = textacy.make_spacy_doc(record, lang="en_core_web_sm")
    print(list(textacy.extract.triples.direct_quotations(doc)))
```

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/72578417/3) to the question [Extract quotations and attribution from text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72578417/extract-quotations-and-attribution-from-text) by the OP [jedmund](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19146242/jedmund) under CC BY-SA 4.0.</sub>